# How to achieve "flying Arcs" as link in the force layout of D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

Please suggest how to achieve the flying arcs in the force layout of d3.JS.
As in the image[image]

Comment: Not sure ...do you want the force layout to have link path to be in a curve and not straight line?

Comment: Yes in force layout. something like this http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4973620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/cyril123/ov1bjrq9/4/

The idea is to make the curve path between two nodes.
The mechanism to make curve(or the d attribute of a path)

Lives here inside the tick function:
Feel free to change it as per your choice.

```
link.attr("d", 
    function(d){
     var s=d.source; 
     var t = d.target;
     return lineFunction([
     {x:s.x, y: s.y},//start point of curve
     {x:(s.x+t.x)/2, y: (s.y+t.y)/2+30}, //middle point of curve
     {x:s.x, y: t.y} ////end point of curve
    ])
    }
);
```